# mysql pivot dynamic tables and return only where count > 0

Tags: mysql, count, pivot, case

I have a query with this count cases that I use to pivot some totals based on case. This is the query:

```
$user_attrib = some_value;
$user_size = some_value;
$items = [218, 219];
$items = join(",", $items);


SELECT owned_items.model_id,
       Count(owned_items.model_size_id) AS total_owned,
       makes.make,
       items.model_name,
       items.picture,
       items.color,
       items.material,
       Count(CASE item_sizes.id WHEN '1' THEN item_sizes.id ELSE NULL END) AS '1',
       Count(CASE item_sizes.id WHEN '2' THEN item_sizes.id ELSE NULL END) AS '2',
       Count(CASE item_sizes.id WHEN '3' THEN item_sizes.id ELSE NULL END) AS '3',
       Count(CASE item_sizes.id WHEN '4' THEN item_sizes.id ELSE NULL END) AS '4',
       Count(CASE item_sizes.id WHEN '5' THEN item_sizes.id ELSE NULL END) AS '5',
       Count(CASE item_sizes.id WHEN '6' THEN item_sizes.id ELSE NULL END) AS '6',
       Count(CASE item_sizes.id WHEN '7' THEN item_sizes.id ELSE NULL END) AS '7',
       Count(CASE item_sizes.id WHEN '8' THEN item_sizes.id ELSE NULL END) AS '8',
       Count(CASE item_sizes.id WHEN '9' THEN item_sizes.id ELSE NULL END) AS '9',
       Count(CASE item_sizes.id WHEN '10' THEN item_sizes.id ELSE NULL END) AS '10',
       Count(CASE item_sizes.id WHEN '11' THEN item_sizes.id ELSE NULL END) AS '11',
       Count(CASE item_sizes.id WHEN '12' THEN item_sizes.id ELSE NULL END) AS '12',
       Count(CASE item_sizes.id WHEN '13' THEN item_sizes.id ELSE NULL END) AS '13',
       Count(CASE item_sizes.id WHEN '14' THEN item_sizes.id ELSE NULL END) AS '14',
       Count(CASE item_sizes.id WHEN '15' THEN item_sizes.id ELSE NULL END) AS '15'
FROM   owned_items
       INNER JOIN owned_item_user
               ON owned_items.id = owned_item_user.owned_item_id
       INNER JOIN users
               ON owned_item_user.user_id = users.id
       INNER JOIN item_sizes
               ON owned_items.model_size_id = item_sizes.id
       INNER JOIN items
               ON owned_items.model_id = items.id
       INNER JOIN makes
               ON owned_items.make_id = makes.id      
WHERE  users.attrib_id = $user_attrib
       AND users.size_id = $user_size
       AND owned_items.model_id IN ($items)
GROUP  BY owned_items.model_id
```

I'd like to generalize the data so that if I add a 16th case I don't have to manually add another line and I would like to return only cases that have results > 0.
For the first part I tried with this [pivot dynamic tables](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html) adapting code without success. Second part I tried to set `HAVING Count(CASE item_sizes.id WHEN '1' THEN item_sizes.id ELSE NULL END) AS '1' > 0` (etc..) without success either.

Comment: when you say `return only cases that have results > 0` are you referring to  the entire row? or are you referring to the columns?   PS. the entire query is actually relevant if you have joins/outer joins

Comment: I want to get only pivoted columns ('1' , '2. ... 'n') that have data > 0 . I'll post the whole query.

Comment: I put the complete query

Comment: the only way you can get just the columns that have data in them, you would need to build the COUNT(Case) portion of your query dynamically.  The link you posted (pivot dynamic tables) shows you how to do this.  You just have to use the same query with the same joins to get only the `item_sizes.id` that are valid

Comment: so how would you modify the query based on the link?  I tried but I get an error.

Comment: i'm not super familiar with mysql, but it might look something like this  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc782

Comment: hm, no, that code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Group By + Count

```
Select item_sizes.id, count(*) from item_sizes where item_sizes.id between 1 and 15 group by item_sizes.id;
```

Comment: ... I am pivoting the data, creating columns that don't exist in the DB ( '1', '2, .., '15')